# Solr 6 how to use dateRange math with localParam op

Tags: solr, date-range, date-math

1) I have a `dateRange` type field in solr 6, 
It contains date ranges.

2) following query will give all the matching record which has date range from **1st jan 2017 To 31st dec 2017**.

`fq={!field f=dateRange op=Contains}[2017 TO 2017]`

3) Following 2 queries are also working

`fq=dateRange:[* TO NOW-1DAY]`

`fq={!field f=dateRange op=Contains}[2017-07-08 TO 2017-08-21]`

**My Question is :**

Now I wants to fetch all date range from **1st Jan 2017 to 2017 -1DAY**
I have tried with following query but getting error.

`fq={!field f=dateRange op=Contains}[2017 TO 2017-1DAY]`

> "msg":"Couldn't parse date because: Improperly formatted date:
>   2017-1DAY",

Why dateRange math with localParam op is not working?

Comment: My guess is that first of all you want them in the different order (i.e. `[2017-1DAY TO ..]`, but I'd try giving it as the complete date: `2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z-1DAY`

Comment: I have tried 
`fq={!field f=dateRange op=Contains}[2017-01-01 TO 2017-12-31T00:00:000Z-1DAY]` 

but getting same error
"Couldn't parse date because: Improperly formatted date: 2017-12-31T00:00:000Z-1DAY"